# In app billing on configuration change

Tags: android, in-app-billing, screen-rotation

When rotating my screen I'm losing my connection to in app billing. This is my `onDestroy` method below:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            Log.d(tag, "Destroying helper.");
            if (mHelper != null) {
                mHelper.dispose();
                mHelper = null;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy " + mHelper, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Which shows that mHelper is still not null when the screen orientation is changing as the activity is not finishing, then after this in my onCreate method, `mHelper` is null.

How can I prevent a screen rotation doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an orientation change will cause the system to destroy and recreate your Activity, to change this behavior change the Activity's entry in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

which tells Android that you wish handle configurations change yourself, so the Activity will not be restarted when an orientation change occur, but your current Activity instance's onConfigurationChanged() method will be called.

An example of singleton:

```
public class SingletonObjectDemo {

    private static SingletonObject singletonObject;
    // Note that the constructor is private
    private SingletonObjectDemo() {
        // Optional Code
    }
    public static SingletonObjectDemo getSingletonObject() {
        if (singletonObject == null) {
            singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
        }
        return singletonObject;
    }
}
```

You can check out more info on how orientation change is handled [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Thank you! The problem I expect with this is that it will prevent my activity from being recreated, thus fail to change to the landscape activity layout.

Comment: In this case I guess you can pass a global context to mHelper (an Application instance), and keep a reference to mHelper either as a static variable or keep it in a singleton

Comment: Thanks once again Kai. What do you mean keep it as a singleton? And holding it as a static variable is nothing more than typing static right? My sqlite database connection is a static one and this also doesn't remain. I tried passing in the application context but this didn't work either.

Comment: modified my answer to add a Singleton example. Yes you can just add "static" keyword. What do you mean by 'passing in the application context'?

Comment: It worked! Thank you :D (it being just adding static to each variable that was depended on)